# Polynomial division: the degree of the remainder

Tags: polynomials, euclidean-algorithm

Suppose that $P,Q\in\mathbb F_p[x]$ are monic, nonconstant polynomials with $\deg P+\deg Q=p$. Let $R$ be the remainder of division of $PQ$ by $x^p-x$; that is,
$$PQ=(x^p-x)+R(x),\quad \deg R<p.$$ Can one express explicitly the degree of $R$ in terms of the degrees $m=\deg P$ and $n=\deg Q$, or at least say something strong about $\deg R$?

In addition to $m+n=p$, one can assume that $p$ is large, $m<0.9p$, and also $\deg R<0.9p$.

Comment: Note that for $P:= x$ and $Q:= x^{p-1} - 1$ we have $R = 0$ and for $P:= x$ and $Q:= x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} - 1$ we have $\deg(R) = p-1$

Answer (score 1):

Assume $m,n < .9p$.

Here's a partial result . . .

**Claim:**$\;$For any integer $r$ in the range $.1p < r < .9p$, it's always possible to have $\deg R = r$.

**Proof:**$\;$Fix an integer $r$ such that $.1p < r < .9p$, and let $P,Q$ be given by
\begin{align*}
P&=\prod_{k=0}^{r-1}(x-k)\\[4pt]
Q&=1+\prod_{k=r}^p(x-k)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Then we have $m,n < .9p$ and $m+n=p$, and from the identity
$$x^p-x=\prod_{k=0}^{p}(x-k)$$
it follows that
$$PQ=(x^p-x)+P$$
hence $R=P$, so $\deg(R)=r$.

**Note:**$\;$If instead of the restriction $m,n < .9p$, we only require $m,n < p$, then using the same construction, we get that $r$ can be any integer in the range $1 \le r \le p-1$.

Comment: The restriction is not $m,n<0.9$ but $m,\deg R<0.9p$. Still, your example works, thank you. I plan to post the real problem shortly.